# str.indexOf returning "Is not a function" error

Tags: javascript

Goal:  I have a string of code that is looking to compare two parameters.  If one of the parameters is not contained within the other parameter, I need to execute a script.

Good things: The script to hide everything (in the code below, everything after "if(a > 0);") works perfectly.

Issue: When I add the indexOf function to try to do the comparison, I get an error saying:  Uncaught TypeError: str.indexOf is not a function

What I've tried:  I initially tried the str.includes function but found through research that that function is not supported in all browsers and was directed to try doing the indexOf function.  Everything I've found online seems to say that the indexOf function should work?

My code is:

```
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
     var str = [@authfield:Authentications_2_Region];
     var a = str.indexOf([@field:Location_2_Region_GL]);
     if(a > 0);
     function hide_column(column_order)
{
     var tbl = document.getElementsByTagName("table")[0];
     var table_header = tbl.getElementsByTagName('th')[column_order];
     table_header.style.display=stl;
     var rows = tbl.getElementsByTagName('tr');
     for (var row=1; row<rows.length;row++)
        {     
            var cels = rows[row].getElementsByTagName('td');
            cels[column_order].style.display=stl;
        }
}

var stl='none';
hide_column(0);
hide_column(1);
hide_column(2);
hide_column(3);
hide_column(4);
hide_column(5);
hide_column(6);
</script>
```

I'm not good with Javascript, any help is appreciated.

Comment: try changing this line var str = [@authfield:Authentications_2_Region]; to var str = [@authfield:Authentications_2_Region].value(); and see if it works

Comment: Error happens because you pass field to the indexOf function and no indexOf function takes a field, try @Satya answer to correct that

Comment: That returns"Uncaught TypeError: 19.value is not a function" - it seemed that it liked all the code until it got to the indexOf function - when I altered this line it produced the error earlier in the string and didn't get as far as the indexOf function.

Comment: Got it - I needed to convert the parameter to a string.  Thank you @Satya!

Comment: anytime @AlexFenech

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @Satya - he got me in the right direction.  I needed to convert the parameters to a string.  Successful code is

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
     var str = toString([@authfield:Authentications_2_Region]); 
     var a = str.indexOf(toString([@field:Location_2_Region_GL]));
     if(a > 0);
     function hide_column(column_order)
{
     var tbl = document.getElementsByTagName("table")[0];
     var table_header = tbl.getElementsByTagName('th')[column_order];
     table_header.style.display=stl;
     var rows = tbl.getElementsByTagName('tr');
     for (var row=1; row<rows.length;row++)
        {     
            var cels = rows[row].getElementsByTagName('td');
            cels[column_order].style.display=stl;
        }
}

var stl='none';
hide_column(0);
hide_column(1);
hide_column(2);
hide_column(3);
hide_column(4);
hide_column(5);
hide_column(6);
</script>
```